# DBMS OUTPUT doesn't work

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dbms-output

I need a piece of advice there. I'm using Oracle Developer for a few anonymous PL/SQL blocks. The problem is that when I run it, the `dbms_output` don't give me anything even though the script is correct (anonymous block completed).

What is wrong? What am I missing? I already enabled the `dbms_output` connection and the test seems to be ok.

```
set serveroutput on size 30000;

DECLARE
  CURSOR my_curs IS 
     SELECT studenti.nume, 
            studenti.prenume, 
            studenti.an, 
            note_studenti.nota, 
            obiecte.den 
       FROM studenti 
      INNER JOIN  note_studenti 
         ON studenti.mat = note_studenti.mat 
      INNER JOIN  obiecte 
         ON note_studenti.cod = obiecte.cod;

  v_nume     studenti.nume%TYPE;
  v_prenume  studenti.prenume%TYPE;
  v_an       studenti.an%TYPE;
  v_nota     note_studenti.nota%TYPE;
  v_ob       obiecte.den%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  OPEN my_curs;
  LOOP 
    FETCH my_curs INTO v_nume, v_prenume, v_an, v_nota, v_ob;
    EXIT WHEN my_curs%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_nume || ' '   || v_prenume ||
                        ' este in anul '  || v_an      ||
                        ' si a luat nota '|| v_nota    || 
                        ' la obiectul '   || v_ob);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: If you use SQL*Developer, you can try View->Show DBMS Output, it pops up a window printting, the info there.

Comment: I already did that. I have the DBMS Output windows on the bottom of my SQL Developer main windows, but doesn't print anything when I run the program.

Comment: then, your query isnt return anything? Can you try running it separately?

Comment: Also, in the dbms windows, there would be a plus sign, click and select the database you run!

Comment: Have you called `DBMS_OUTPUT` beforehand?

Comment: How do you know you should get any results?  try dbms_output.put_line('Beginning') right after BEGIN and you should see this output (once the entire script is finished that is)

Comment: tbone, you are right :) but now...what is the problem in my script? shouldn't it return the informations that I'm asking for?

Comment: LE: Now I undestand. The script is ok, but the problem is somewhere in the conexion from this script and the databse (created in SQL Command Line). The conexion (I made it in SQL Developer by pressing CTRL N) is just fine, and when I test it I get a succes message). What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: LE2: I just found the problem. I was trying to do this with both  ORACLE SQL Developer and SQL Command Line opened. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: +1 - solved own problem

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure.... Does the cursor query fetch any data? The DBMS_Output will not output anything if there is no data!

Answer (score 0):

I’m using SQL developer too and I have the same issue , but it works fine in the SQL workshop in the web browser. So give it a try.